# How to search archived items in Sitecore content editor?

Tags: search, sitecore, sitecore6

Sitecore content editor interface offers several search interfaces – search application from Sitecore button, search input field above content tree and search down right by database selector.
As far as I see no of them allow search in archived item. I know that Archive application has its own search, but users do not want to start archive application in order to search items there.

The question is how to include search result of archived into general Sitecore search?

Answer (score 1):

in the buckets module (or sitecore7) the indexing/searching pipeline is more open to modification. 
This will make it possible to achieve the thing you want, possibly by hooking in to the searcher and performing a search in the archive index (which you'd have to make).

kind regards,
remco